# How to make PyCharm IDE use the OS terminal when I run my program?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pycharm, gnome-terminal

When I run my terminal (non GUI) program from PyCharm (Community Edition) it shows the output in a tab at the bottom of the IDE screen.

I don't want that. I want my program to show its output in the OS terminal (which is the gnome-terminal in my case because I am using Ubuntu) like if I ran my .py file by typing: **python filename.py** into the terminal.

How can I set PyCharm up to work that way?

Comment: Does just running it in the terminal not fit your needs?

Comment: It would be nice if I could do that from PyCharm.